# encodeURI (or encodeURIComponent) returns different encodings in different parts of my code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

(disclaimer: this is the first time I post a question on SO, so I apologize in advance if I did anything wrong)

I have an URI pointing to an image with this structure:

> (stuff...)/acryagl_violencia física/(more stuff...).jpg

I tried to encode it but I get two different results in two different script files and I don't see the reason why.

```
// Script one:
`stuff.../${ encodeURIComponent(element.article_id_thumbnail) }/...stuff`
// I get 'acryagl_violencia%20fi%CC%81sica', which does NOT work

// Script two (and Chrome console):
`stuff.../${ encodeURIComponent(element.id) }/...stuff`
// I get 'acryagl_violencia%20f%C3%ADsica', which DOES work

// Notice the difference is on the 'í' from 'física'
```

According to https://www.url-encode-decode.com/, both strings should decode to the same, which is weird to me. I am totally lost on this one.

In case it helps, this is a React + Vite project, although I don't see how this could be related with the bundler. I am also testing everything on Chrome.

I fixed it by manually encoding the `í` character, but there should be a better fix.
Has anyone faced this problem before?

Comment: Are you sure the two values are the same? Because when i do `encodeURIComponent("acryagl_violencia física")` in the Chrome console I get the same as the first script.

Comment: what is the value of `element.article_id_thumbnail` and `element.id` ?

Comment: _"both strings should decode to the same"_ - they might _look_ the same when rendered, but they aren't the same. In the second case, you got `C3 AD`, which is unicode code point `U+00ED`, an _actual_ `í` character. In the first case, there is a _normal_ `i`, followed by `CC 81`, code point `0301`, which is the COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT character. Your _input data_ was different here, and so you get a different result as well.

Comment: this is not a matter of function the problem here is that the source string is different from the start

Comment: @TachibanaShin "different"/"same" is not a concrete concept in unicode when looking at byte sequences.

Comment: @spender clearly 1 byte is different from 2 bytes. If you see the two strings as the same, it's just that your font automatically merges them. in standard fonts like japanese i see 2 completely different strings

Comment: @TachibanaShin Indeed, but, in their normalized forms, the strings become the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code works well, it's the source data that seem to be inconsistent:

- your first string contains letter "i" followed by [combining acute accent (U+0301)](https://graphemica.com/0301)
- your second string contains [latin small letter i with acute (U+00ED)](https://graphemica.com/%C3%AD)

You might need to use [`normalize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize) somewhere in your content handling pipeline to get them consistent.

```js
console.log(
 decodeURI('%C3%AD').normalize('NFKD')
 ===
 decodeURI('i%CC%81')
); // true
// both are two (same) codepoints;
// first was decomposed from single codepoint

console.log(
 decodeURI('%C3%AD')
 ===
 decodeURI('i%CC%81').normalize('NFKC')
); // true
// both are same single codepoint;
// second was composed into it from two codepoints
```

Comment: Great! This worked! I accept this one since both answers work but this one helped me understand better the source of the problem. Thanks a lot! :D

Comment: Side note: It's weird though that they are inconsistent since they are connected by a foreign key in the database, so MySQL thinks they are similar enough to pass the check...

Comment: Hm, that sound like an interesting MySQL question; some implicit normalization during lookup sounds plausible, yet matching differently normalized Unicode sequences in foreign keys feels … strange. But would probably make sense as well.

Answer (score 0):

[`String.prototype.normalize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize) to the rescue:

`encodeURIComponent(element.article_id_thumbnail.normalize())`

and

`encodeURIComponent(element.id.normalize())`

should give you the result you are looking for.

```js
const a = encodeURIComponent(decodeURIComponent("acryagl_violencia%20fi%CC%81sica").normalize())
const b = encodeURIComponent(decodeURIComponent("acryagl_violencia%20f%C3%ADsica").normalize())
console.log(a === b) // true
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked like a charm :) Accepting the other answer simply because it helped me understand the reason why my code was failing